# Unable to lookup XML value from imported document for XSLT-1

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

This is driving me mad. :(

XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:msa="http://www.publictalksoftware.co.uk/msa">
    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" version="4.01"
      doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"
      doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"/>

    <xsl:variable name="Trans" select="document('Group--Field Service Groups-Translations.xml')"/>

    <!-- Set the language code (we need to take into account the Foreign Language Group mode) -->
    <xsl:variable name="LangCode">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="//Settings/ForeignGroupMode='1'">
                <xsl:value-of select="//Settings/ForeignGroupLanguageCode"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="//Settings/LanguageCode"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:variable>

    <!-- Set the language direction (we need to take into account the Foreign Language Group mode) -->
    <xsl:variable name="LangDirection">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="//Settings/ForeignGroupMode='1'">
                <xsl:value-of select="//Settings/ForeignGroupDirection"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="//Settings/Direction"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <xsl:attribute name="lang">
                <xsl:value-of select="$LangCode"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="dir">
                <xsl:value-of select="$LangDirection"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <head>
                <title>
                    Field Service Groups
                </title>
            </head>
            <body>
                <h1>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$Trans/msa:Translations/msa:*[local-name() = $LangCode]/msa:Heading"/>
                </h1>
                <h2>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$LangCode"/>
                </h2>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The XML that is imported:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Translations xmlns="http://www.publictalksoftware.co.uk/msa">
    <!-- Afrikaans -->
    <af>
        <Heading>Field Service Groups</Heading>
    </af>
    <!-- Albanian -->
    <sq>
        <Heading>Field Service Groups</Heading>
    </sq>
    <!-- Amharic -->
    <am>
        <Heading>የመስክ አገልግሎት ቡድኖች</Heading>
    </am>
    <!-- Arabic-->
    <ar>
        <Heading>فرق خدمة الحقل</Heading>
    </ar>
    <!-- Armenian -->
    <hy>
        <Heading>Field Service Groups</Heading>
    </hy>
    <!-- Aukan -->
    <drk>
        <Heading>Field Service Groups</Heading>
    </drk>
    <!-- Bulgarian -->
    <bg>
        <Heading>Field Service Groups</Heading>
    </bg>
    <!-- Cebuano -->
    <ceb>
        <Heading>Field Service Groups</Heading>
    </ceb>
    <!-- Chinese Simplified -->
    <zh-Hans>
        <Heading>传道小组</Heading>
    </zh-Hans>
    <!-- Cibemba -->
    <bem>
        <Heading>Field Service Groups</Heading>
    </bem>
    <!-- Croatian -->
    <hr>
        <Heading>Grupe za službu propovijedanja</Heading>
    </hr>
    <!-- Czech -->
    <cs>
        <Heading>Field Service Groups</Heading>
    </cs>
    <!-- Danish -->
    <da>
        <Heading>Tjenestegrupper</Heading>
    </da>
    <!-- Dutch -->
    <nl>
        <Heading>Field Service Groups</Heading>
    </nl>
    <!-- English and Pidgin (West Africa) -->
    <en>
        <Heading>Field Service Groups</Heading>
    </en>
    <!-- Estonian -->
    <et>
        <Heading>Field Service Groups</Heading>
    </et>
    <!-- Finnish -->
    <fi>
        <Heading>Field Service Groups</Heading>
    </fi>
    <!-- French and Saramaccan -->
    <fr>
        <Heading>Field Service Groups</Heading>
    </fr>
    <!-- German -->
    <de>
        <Heading>Field Service Groups</Heading>
    </de>
    <!-- Greek -->
    <el>
        <Heading>Field Service Groups</Heading>
    </el>
    <!-- Gujarati -->
    <gu>
        <Heading>ક્ષેત્ર સેવા જૂથ</Heading>
    </gu>
    <!-- Gun -->
    <guw>
        <Heading>Field Service Groups</Heading>
    </guw>
    <!-- Haitian Creole -->
    <ht>
        <Heading>Field Service Groups</Heading>
    </ht>
    <!-- Hindi -->
    <hi>
        <Heading>Field Service Groups</Heading>
    </hi>
    <!-- Hungarian -->
    <hu>
        <Heading>Field Service Groups</Heading>
    </hu>
    <!-- Indonesian -->
    <id>
        <Heading>Kelompok Dinas Lapangan</Heading>
    </id>
    <!-- Italian -->
    <it>
        <Heading>Field Service Groups</Heading>
    </it>
    <!-- Japanese -->
    <ja>
        <Heading>Field Service Groups</Heading>
    </ja>
    <!-- Lingala -->
    <ln>
        <Heading>Field Service Groups</Heading>
    </ln>
    <!-- Malagasy -->
    <mg>
        <Heading>Field Service Groups</Heading>
    </mg>
    <!-- Maltese -->
    <mt>
        <Heading>Field Service Groups</Heading>
    </mt>
    <!-- Polish -->
    <pl>
        <Heading>Field Service Groups</Heading>
    </pl>
    <!-- Portuguese -->
    <pt>
        <Heading>Grupos de serviço de campo</Heading>
    </pt>
    <!-- Punjabi -->
    <pa>
        <Heading>ਪ੍ਰਚਾਰ ਗਰੁੱਪ</Heading>
    </pa>
    <!-- Romanian -->
    <ro>
        <Heading>Field Service Groups</Heading>
    </ro>
    <!-- Russian -->
    <ru>
        <Heading>Field Service Groups</Heading>
    </ru>
    <!-- Sesotho (South Africa) -->
    <st>
        <Heading>Field Service Groups</Heading>
    </st>
    <!-- Setswana -->
    <tn>
        <Heading>Setlhopha sa Tirelo ya Tshimo</Heading>
    </tn>
    <!-- Slovenian -->
    <sl>
        <Heading>Field Service Groups</Heading>
    </sl>
    <!-- Spanish -->
    <es>
        <Heading>Field Service Groups</Heading>
    </es>
    <!-- Sranantongo -->
    <srn>
        <Heading>Field Service Groups</Heading>
    </srn>
    <!-- Swahili -->
    <sw>
        <Heading>Vikundi vya Utumishi wa Shambani</Heading>
    </sw>
    <!-- Swedish -->
    <sv>
        <Heading>Tjänstegrupper</Heading>
    </sv>
    <!-- Tagalog -->
    <tl>
        <Heading>Grupo sa Paglilingkod sa Larangan</Heading>
    </tl>
    <!-- Tamil -->
    <ta>
        <Heading>Field Service Groups</Heading>
    </ta>
    <!-- Tsonga -->
    <ts>
        <Heading>Field Service Groups</Heading>
    </ts>
    <!-- Turkish -->
    <tr>
        <Heading>Field Service Groups</Heading>
    </tr>
    <!-- Twi -->
    <tw>
        <Heading>Field Service Groups</Heading>
    </tw>
    <!-- Ukrainian -->
    <uk>
        <Heading>Field Service Groups</Heading>
    </uk>
    <!-- Vietnamese -->
    <vi>
        <Heading>Field Service Groups</Heading>
    </vi>
    <!-- Zulu -->
    <zu>
        <Heading>Amaqembu Enkonzo Yasensimini</Heading>
    </zu>
</Translations>
```

And the XML used for the transformation:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="Group--Field Service Groups2.xsl"?>
<FieldServiceGroupReport>
    <Settings>
        <LanguageCode>en</LanguageCode>
        <Direction>ltr</Direction>
    </Settings>
</FieldServiceGroupReport>
```

All I am seeing in the output is en.

Why can't I display the correct heading based on the `LangCode` value lookup in the imported document? Driving me mad.

The `<h2>` output correctly displays en. But when I use the lookup it should be showing me "Field Service Groups".

Comment: While asking an XSLT question you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) Well-formed input XML.
(2) Your logic, and XSLT stylesheet that tries to implement it.
(3) Desired output, based on the sample XML in the #1 above.
(4) XSLT processor and its conformance with the XSLT standards: 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, or 4.0.

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky I did tag it 1-0. Using Edge browser.

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky It doesn't like the spaced in the file name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the file name being imported had spaces. So I had to encode it:

```
<xsl:variable name="Translations" select="document('Group--Field%20Service%20Groups-Translations.xml')"/>
```

Comment: Please mark your answer as an Accepted Answer.

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky I can't mark it for 2 days.

Comment: Note that the problem is processor-specific. For example, Xalan and Saxon have no problem with spaces in the filename. --- P.S. A document accessed using the `document()` function is NOT "imported". That term is taken:  https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116/#import